# Get array of custom attribute values by finding class and checked checkbox type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have few checkboxes and those elements contain a custom attribute named `data-id`. For example:

```
<input class="testCheckbox" icheck="" ng-model="Model" data-id="57e3"type="checkbox">
```

I want to receive an array of ids by finding it by class name and type of the element. Currently I have something like this and it works:

```
var testIds = [];
$('input.testCheckbox[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    testIds.push($(this).attr("data-id"))
});
```

I am wondering if there is inline function in jQuery which can return the same result? I've tried with this code but it only returns first value:

```
console.log($('input.testCheckbox[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr("data-id"));
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong? Best regards.

Comment: without each or map you cannot do this . it will return only first value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no inline function to do this, but you can shorten your code by using `map()` instead:

```
var testIds = $('input.testCheckbox[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('id');
}).get();
```

Comment: what is the use of get method ??

Comment: It returns the underlying array directly, instead of having it wrapped in a jQuery object. See http://api.jquery.com/get for more info

Comment: how do we know which get method is this ?? jquery also has this get method .. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: That is `$.get()` - ie. for making GET AJAX requests

Comment: $.method() is used for ajax and $().method() used for javascript ?? right

Comment: Well, both are jQuery constructs, not native Javascript at all.